# Vue.js + PHP project + translations

Tags: php, vue.js

I'm currently working on project which is written in PHP. On some pages I use Vue.js and I want to implement i18n translations for Vue component, that is integrated with translations for PHP application (translations are fetching from database). I look for solution for my problem. One of possible (my preferred): writing webpack plugin, extract all call function (e.q. __) and put arguments of these function in separated PHP file, and then load this file as source of translations (in runtime). Example generated PHP file:

```
<?php
$translations = [
    'extracted1' => $this->translate('extracted1'),
    'extracted2' => $this->translate('extracted2'),
];

echo json_encode($translations);
```

Is this is good approach?

Comment: You should use some I18n package for VueJS that is already made, then what you can think about is how to fill the translations with data from PHP.

You could fetch all the translations for a given language on Application start for example

Comment: But application have a lot of translations and I want to extract only used in vuejs code (because file with all translations is big and generation time is not acceptable).